# How to implement UIAlertcontroller as PopOver(with arrow direction up) in a UIBarbutton

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller

I know that this is old school question - but I did searched the web and found solutions to be deprecated. How would I implement a **UIAlertcontroller** as **popOver(with arrow direction up)** in a **barButton**. Here's the code:

```
 - (IBAction)eventSortingAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

UIAlertController * view=   [UIAlertController
                         alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                         message:@"Select you Choice"
                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                 actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                     //Do some thing here
                     [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                 }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                         [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
[view addAction:ok];
[view addAction:cancel];
[view setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
view.modalInPopover = YES;
view.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
view.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];

UIView* senderView = [sender valueForKey:@"view"]; //HACK
UIPopoverPresentationController* popover = view.popoverPresentationController;
if (popover) {
   popover.sourceView = senderView;
   popover.sourceRect = senderView.bounds;
   popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
   popover.barButtonItem = self.actionBarButton;
   popover.delegate = self;
}}
```

apparently I always got a "popover = nil".  Please Help! Thanks in advance!

By the way this code is not mine, just testing it in Xcode.

Comment: Update your question with the code that actually creates the `UIAlertController`. And explain what is actually happening with the code you posted versus what you want it to do.

Comment: Hi rmaddy i posted the updated question below.  I cannot edit my question - still lacking Reputation.

Comment: Sure you can edit. Click the edit link under your question. Don't post an answer.

Comment: Thanks didn't able to see, there updated it.  So what I really want is the have a alert msg that that anchors(has an arrow pointing to the uibarbutton) with the uibarbutton that i have. What happen actually is that it show the conventional alert controlle

Answer (score 3):

Just a reminded because this is a top result on Google :

popPresenter.barButtonItem is an alternative to popPresenter.sourceView+popPresenter.sourceRect

[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWeQz.png) [(source)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/1622314-barbuttonitem)

Regarding OP question, `IBAction` parameter `sender` should be used.

```c
UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alertController
                                             popoverPresentationController];
popPresenter.barButtonItem = sender;
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                         message:nil
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *actnCamera = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Camera" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                   }];

UIAlertAction *actnLibrary = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Library" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                    }];

[alertController addAction:actnLibrary];
[alertController addAction:actnCamera];
[alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alertController
                                                 popoverPresentationController];
popPresenter.sourceView = self.view;
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
frame.origin.x = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.width;
popPresenter.sourceRect = frame;
popPresenter.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: hi PKT it doesnt work, it just shows the alertcontroller when i clicked the uibarbutton.  What i wanted to do is that when i click the uibarbutton is something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805608/present-a-uialertcontroller-from-within-a-popover-in-ios8

Comment: Im simulating in iPhone and still I cant implement this. Can this be only done in iPad? Or Im just wrong in implementing this. I have copied and pasted your code.

Comment: for iphone create custom class that contains tableview and present it on your call as popover might solve your problem ....

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and explain how your answer fixes the issue.