# UIBarButtonItem gives me wrong frame for popoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uipopover

I have a toolbar with a `UIBarButtomItem` at the left corner with the label Admin

[image]

I need to show a popover when it taps it, but it appears in a wrong place, it appears at the top left of the screen:

[image]

This is the function to open the popover:

```
// this IBAction is assigned only to the Admin bar button item
@IBAction func openAdmin(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Elige una opción", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    // action button initializations... ... ...

    let barButtonItemSize = sender.valueForKey("view")

    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = barButtonItemSize!.frame

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Also I get this warning on the console when I touch the Admin bar button:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates

What am I doing wrong? or What do I need to do to present the popover at the top of the Admin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = barButtonItemSize!.frame
```

with

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't assign sender to sourceView because the sender is not `UIView` type.

Comment: then try to set `alertController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender` refer [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830807/how-to-implement-uialertcontroller-as-popoverwith-arrow-direction-up-in-a-uiba)

Comment: It works !! thank you!! But I'm still getting the warning on the console: Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

Comment: You're welcome..!! This warning Happens usually when a view appear with animation while animation from a previous view is not completed. Just search this warning in google and you will got many solutions for that with different case. and this is not much serious issue!!